# Dart Flutter _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) listyukle Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a code like this:

```
  void saveList() async {
    final prefences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefences.setStringList("tests", prefences.getStringList("tests")! + ["English / A1 / Family / Test 1"]);
    setState(() {
    });
  }
```

I'm calling the `saveList` function somewhere. When I call it, I get an error like this:

[image]

```
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) saveList
```

It gives the error on this line:

```
prefences.setStringList("tests", prefences.getStringList("tests")! + ["Ingilizce / A1 / Aile / Test 1"]);
```

How can I solve it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first time you call this line, `"tests"` has never been set before in `prefences`, then `prefences.getStringList("tests")` is `null`.

Try this to fix it:

```
  void saveList() async {
    final prefences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> previousList = prefences.getStringList("tests") ?? [];
    prefences.setStringList("tests", previousList + ["English / A1 / Family / Test 1"]);
    setState(() {
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `getStringList` where it might be `null` even though you have used `!`.
[According to the documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

```
// Try reading data from the 'items' key. If it doesn't exist, returns null.
final List<String>? items = prefs.getStringList('items');
```

Thus, you can change your code in order to make sure the value is never `null` but it's an array even though it will be empty. Your example will be

```
  void saveList() async {
    final prefences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final existingValues =
        prefences.getStringList("tests") ?? []; // always a List

    prefences.setStringList(
      "tests",
      [...existingValues, "English / A1 / Family / Test 1"],
    );

    setState(() {});
  }
```